# PHP SimpleXML recursive function to list children and attributes

Tags: php, xml, configuration, recursion, simplexml

I need some help on the SimpleXML calls for a recursive function that lists the elements name and attributes. Making a XML config file system but each script will have it's own config file as well as a new naming convention. So what I need is an easy way to map out all the elements that have attributes, so like in example 1 I need a simple way to call all the processes but I don't know how to do this without hard coding the elements name is the function call. Is there a way to recursively call a function to match a child element name? I did see the xpath functionality but I don't see how to use this for attributes.

Also does the XML in the examples look correct? can I structure my XML like this?

Example 1:

```
<application>
  <processes>
    <process id="123" name="run batch A" />
    <process id="122" name="run batch B" />
    <process id="129" name="run batch C" />
  </processes>
  <connections>
    <databases>
      <database usr="test" pss="test" hst="test" dbn="test" />
    </databases>
    <shells>
      <ssh usr="test" pss="test" hst="test-2" />
      <ssh usr="test" pss="test" hst="test-1" />
    </shells>
  </connections>
</application>
```

Example 2:

```
<config>
  <queues>
    <queue id="1" name="test" />
    <queue id="2" name="production" />
    <queue id="3" name="error" />
  </queues>
</config>
```

Pseudo code:

```
// Would return matching process id
getProcess($process_id) {
  return the process attributes as array that are in the XML
}

// Would return matching DBN (database name)
getDatabase($database_name) {
  return the database attributes as array that are in the XML
}

// Would return matching SSH Host
getSSHHost($ssh_host) {
  return the ssh attributes as array that are in the XML
}

// Would return matching SSH User
getSSHUser($ssh_user) {
  return the ssh attributes as array that are in the XML
}

// Would return matching Queue 
getQueue($queue_id) {
  return the queue attributes as array that are in the XML
}
```

EDIT:

Can I pass two parms? on the first method you have suggested @Gordon

I just got it, thnx, see below

```
public function findProcessById($id, $name)
{
    $attr = false;
    $el = $this->xml->xpath("//process[@id='$id'][@name='$name']"); // How do I also filter by the name?
    if($el && count($el) === 1) {
        $attr = (array) $el[0]->attributes();
        $attr = $attr['@attributes'];
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML looks good to me. The only thing I wouldn't do is making *name* an attribute in *process*, because it contains spaces and should be a textnode then (in my opinion). But since SimpleXml does not complain about it, I guess it boils down to personal preference.

I'd likely approach this with a DataFinder class, encapsulating XPath queries, e.g.

```
class XmlFinder
{
    protected $xml;
    public function __construct($xml)
    {
        $this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    }
    public function findProcessById($id)
    {
        $attr = false;
        $el = $this->xml->xpath("//process[@id='$id']");
        if($el && count($el) === 1) {
            $attr = (array) $el[0]->attributes();
            $attr = $attr['@attributes'];
        }
        return $attr;
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

and then use it with

```
$finder = new XmlFinder($xml);
print_r( $finder->findProcessById(122) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 122
    [name] => run batch B
)
```

XPath tutorial:

- http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp

---

An alternative would be to use [SimpleXmlIterator](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/upgrading+php+5/Chapter+6.+Iterators+and+SPL/6.5+SimpleXML+Iterator/) to iterate over the elements. [Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) can be [decorated](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) with other Iterators, so you can do:

```
class XmlFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    protected $filterElement;
    public function setFilterElement($name)
    {
        $this->filterElement = $name;
    }
    public function accept()
    {
        return ($this->current()->getName() === $this->filterElement);
    }
}

$sxi = new XmlFilterIterator(
           new RecursiveIteratorIterator( 
               new SimpleXmlIterator($xml)));

$sxi->setFilterElement('process');

foreach($sxi as $el) {
    var_dump( $el ); // will only give process elements
}
```

You would have to add some more methods to have the filter work for attributes, but this is a rather trivial task.

Introduction to SplIterators:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html

Comment: Thanks a ton, the first solution looks great but I have an error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'. Im passing the file like this. $xml = "/path/to/file.xml"; is this correct?

Comment: @Phill No, it expects the XML string, not the filepath. If you want to pass a filepath, you have to pass `$data_is_url` as third param. See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

Comment: @Phill or replace the call with `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: Hmm, made the change: $this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, NULL, TRUE); but still getting error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' I made the change in the class example you have, is this correct?

Comment: "@Phill or replace the call with simplexml_load_file" replace where? In the constructor?

Comment: @Phill change `$this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);` to `$this->xml = new simplexml_load_file($xml);` If the error keeps coming then, the path is likely incorrect. Try to verify if you can open the path with `file_get_contents()` and see what it contains.

Comment: ok thats what I did and then got this: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'simplexml_load_file' not found in

Comment: @Phill sorry. Remove the new keyword from the function call

Comment: LOL, I miss that as well. Thnx again

Comment: Hey Gordon I had one other question. See Edit

Comment: @Phill Hmm, I think so. Try "//process[@id='$id' and @name='$name']" for an XPath then

Comment: I tried the AND but no go, I did find the solution though. //process[@id='$id'][@name='$name']