# INI Parsing with validation of required fields

Tags: php, validation, ini

I have a rather large INI that I parse out and validate to make sure all the required settings have been set. This is a massive pain if I need to add/remove a INI setting.

In my PHP script I use something like this:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file($this->ini_filename, true);

// Debug Settings
if(isset($ini['debug_settings']['debug'])) {
    $this->debug = $ini['debug_settings']['debug'];   
} else {
    $this->failedINIValidation("['debug_settings']['debug'] not configured in the INI file: ");
}
```

failedINIValidation() sends me a email with the missing INI field/value/etc...

wanted to make this more generic, any thoughts?

Comment: My suggestion would be dont use INI... use XML, make an XSD and use validation via the schema... let libxml do the work for you.. then you only need to change the schema and XML config. For example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php#62032 Now youll proably have to write some specialized code to give more context for the errors generated by libxml, but i would think this can be pretty generic since you have access to the raw error info and can abstract it from there to your special error types/messages which should more or less remain constant.

Comment: understandable about the making the validation easier but I still would have to have some logic on setters/getters, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: what setters/getters? I thought this was a simple validator not a full configuration object for use directly... Basically you just validate the XML... then you transform that xml into an array for use in your actual app (or an array wrapped in a config object)... You could of course use the XML document directly and pull values out of it with xpath but that seems overkill. Your validator and your config object should be seperate from each other. If you need example logic for transforming the xml into an array for general use take a look at the code for `Zend_Config_Xml`.

Comment: I have used this before but it seemed like a bigger overhead then just a ini file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380755/php-simplexml-recursive-function-to-list-children-and-attibutes

Comment: Well that why i would convert to an array... Then you only have the overhead of parsing and conversion, after that youre jsut dealing with a normal array. I would ignore the overahead of the parsing an conversion especially since i would cache a serialized version of the array on disk. That way your only parsing and converting with the configuration file changes. Id say this is a fair trade to modifying application code every time you add or remove a config value.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out as an idea, it's late and I'm tired, but how about a defined array containing the structure you want to check against, running an `array_diff` and then looping over the result (if any) to call `failedINIValidation`.

Then, if you want to add or remove anything from being required in the INI file you simply have to remove the item from the array.

Unless your INI file is really complex I wouldn't worry about overheads. I ran some quick and dirty benchmarking to verify claims I've seen elsewhere: using `parse_ini_file` was quicker than including a configuration file containing a native `array` object.

Comment: It might suffice to use a valid config file to use in comparison.